# Docker Compose to Cloud Run

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-cloud-run

i created a docker compose file containing django apps and postgresql, and it runs perfectly. then I'm confused whether I can deploy this docker compose file to the google container registry to run a cloud run?

```
    version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    image: django-app
    container_name: django_container
    command: >
      bash -c "python manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=nukacola
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=as938899
    container_name: postgres_db
```

thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run a docker-compose configuration on Cloud Run. Cloud Run only supports individual containers.
To run your Django app on Cloud Run, you can do the following.

- Build your docker image for Django locally using the `docker build` command.
- Push the image to GCR using `docker push` command.
- Create a new Cloud Run service and use the newly pushed Docker image.
- Create a Cloud SQL Postgres instance and use its credentials as environment variables in your Cloud Run service.

You can also host your own Compute Engine instance and run docker-compose on it but I would not recommend that.

You can also create a GKE cluster and run Django and Postgres in it but it requires knowledge of Kubernetes(deployments, statefulsets, services etc).